# Styling custom popup menu

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have an image button which displays a popup menu on being pressed.

```
public void showMenu (View v){
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_launch_page, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();

}
```

The menu generated has a dark background. How can I style my popup so that the background color as well as the color on selecting an item be changed. I'm using `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` so no Actionbar is involved anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

okay you can try this here you can set your custom adapter aswell

yourButtonViewObject is the button onwhich you click to show this popupwindow

```
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);

//here you can set your custom adapter aswell
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_item, passyourarrayhere));
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(yourButtonViewObject);
        listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
        listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);

listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(
            ListPopupWindowAppActivity.this);

//when you click on yourButtonViewObject show listPopupWindow like this
listPopupWindow.show();

//and in onItemClick overiden method do similar as you do in listview
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though not exactly an answer to my question, it served the purpose well.

Comment: you can customize this as you can . you can customize adapter with different rowItem to make it cool. if you dont find any answer helping you please mark it as accepted ans :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

```xml
<style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/background_medium_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/BackgroundGray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

```java
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupMenu);
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);

final MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
```

Answer (score 1):

this can help you

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/PopupMenuTextView</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>

    <!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Item Height & Property -->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>

<!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Divider Property -->
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
</style>

<!-- Change Overflow Menu ListView Text Size and Text Size -->
 <style name="PopupMenuTextView" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28dp</item>
</style>

 <!-- Change Overflow Menu Background -->
 <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#888888</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't help, I'm still stuck with dark background and black text